# Custom Button Group in Zurb Foundation 5 with SASS Mixins not displaying correctly

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I'd like to make a rounded button group in a button bar in Foundation using their custom SCSS mixins.

So my mark up looks like this:

```html
    <ul class="contextualButtons">
            <li><a class="buttonUp">Up a Level</a></li>
            <li><a class="buttonEdit">Edit</a></li>
            <li><a class="buttonDelete">Delete File</a></li>
            <li><a class="buttonAddProtocol">Add Protocol</a></li>
            <li><a class="buttonAddFolder">Add Folder</a></li>
            <li><a class="buttonAddFile" data-dropdown="dropFile" >Add a File</a></li>
                <ul id="dropFile" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#"class="add_content" id="add_idcrp_file">Add File</a</li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="add_content" id="add_versioned_file">Add Modifiable File</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a class="buttonPermissions">Permissions</a></li>
            <li><a class="buttonSearch">Search</a></li>
        </ul>
```

And my scss looks like this: (assume I can load foundation elements correctly)

```scss
.contextualButtons { 
    @include button-group-container();
    .buttonUp,
    .buttonEdit,
    .buttonDelete,
    .buttonAddProtocol,
    .buttonAddFolder,
    .buttonAddFile,
    .buttonPermissions,
    .buttonSearch  { 
        @include button(); 
    }
    & > li {
        @include button-group-style($button-round, 8, left);
    }
}
```

It gets pretty close to the [example](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/button_groups.html), but I'm not getting any border between the buttons. If I add .button to each, it works. I'd rather just have one class on each element, keeping things nice and semantic an all.

The individual buttons are going to have icons, so they need to be differentiated from their peers.

Thanks.

## Update

Digging deeper into what compiles, my custom button group class .contextualButtons is not replacing the default .button with my custom button classes.

```css
.contextualButtons > * > .button {
    border-right: 1px solid;
    border-color: rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.5);    
}
.contextualButtons > li:last-child button, .contextualButtons > li:last-child .button {
      border-right: 0;
}

.contextualButtons > li:first-child {
      margin-left: 0;
}
```

Looks like I would be better off extending .button rather than using the button mixin. This isn't what the documentation would seem to indicate, but I understand now thats not how the mixins are written. Might be better to combine button-group container and button-group button class into a single mixin into which two class names (or strings) are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks ok-ish.

```
.contextualButtons { 
    @extend .button-group;
    .buttonUp,
    .buttonEdit,
    .buttonDelete,
    .buttonAddProtocol,
    .buttonAddFolder,
    .buttonAddFile,
    .buttonPermissions,
    .buttonSearch  { 
        @extend .button;
        padding-left: 0.1em;
        padding-right: 0.1em; 

    }
    & > li {
        @include button-group-style($button-round, 8, left);
        margin: .2em;
       & > a {
             word-wrap: break-word;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They are being correctly selected, should have posted compiled CSS for clarity's sake. There is a 1 to 1 match on class names. Not using any default classes or IDs.

Comment: @fontophilic  ok. Might be something like this?

Comment: Hah, I had just finished writing something very similar, down to the word-wrap. Thanks!

Comment: Was it just me, or was the documentation on this confusing?

Comment: @fontophilic most of the time i end up just hacking it until it starts to work properly. Pretty much standard webdev methodology  :P